# How to open a LinkedIn shareArticle link in the LinkedIn app

Tags: javascript, api, linkedin-api

I would like for the following URL to open the LinkedIn app for sharing, rather than opening a new Chrome tab.

https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http://developer.linkedin.com&title=LinkedIn%20Developer%20Network&summary=My%20favorite%20developer%20program&source=LinkedIn

Is this possible? If not, how can this be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a way of using the linkedin api to initialize this on a link like the one you posted (precisely what I am trying to do). And their "documentation" is really frustrating!

For my code:

1. I first check whether it is a small screen (using bootstrap so on
   small screens the hamburger icon will be displaying)
2. Then prevent the default click event from firing
3. Then open in a new popup window (which Linkedin resizes as it loads)

   $('a.linkedin-link').on('click', function(event) {

   var navbar_collapsed = $('#navbar .navbar-toggle').is(':visible');

   // Only use popup on desktop

   if (!navbar_collapsed) {

   ```
   event.preventDefault();

   window.open($(this).attr('href'), 'Share on Linkedin', 'status=no,height=580,width=600,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,location=yes,directories=no');

   }
   ```

   });